# Car loses power after a short while and regains it immediately after I shut off the ignition and turn it back on

Tags: mazda-3

A few weeks ago my car lost power and the check engine light came on. I  scanned the car and found that the spark plugs and ignition coils needed changing. After replacing the plugs and coils the check engine light went away. However, the car doesn't run at its best. After driving for about 10 mins the car becomes very sluggish and idles very very low. Interestingly, whenever I turn off the engine and run it immediately, then car runs well for about 10mins and becomes sluggish again, until I shutdown and restart the car

Comment: Always suspect the last thing you touched.  Double check that the wiring didn't get crossed. Can you swap back in one of the older coils (maybe one of the new ones is bad)

Comment: What Make/Model? If it's a v6 or v8, you might not notice a cylinder not firing, other than the loss in power. I'd recommend checking that all the wires are tightly connected.

Answer (score 2):

guys. I have discovered what was causing the issue. It turns out the throttle position sensor (TPS) was bad. The car's losing power was a safety mechanism to prevent damage to the engine. Thanks for your contributions.